# Logged but not redirecting

Tags: php

When i want to login in my admincp appear an popup with this message(You will be redirected in 3 seconds.) I wait 3-5 sec but nothing happens.

```
if($_GET["islem"] == "giris_yap")
```

https://pastebin.com/u3b6qEKN

Comment: Reformat and enahnce your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code. You haven't use any javascript code to reload the page after successfully login. You can use location.reload(); to reload the page. It is function of javascript so you have to embed in php page like this.

```
   <?php ?>
  <script> location.reload(); </script>
  <?php ?>
```